# Carousel stopping drop-down menu from working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, carousel

I'm making a very basic page with header, small navigation with the last option as a drop-down menu, and a bootstrap carousel plug-in. Since I added the carousel the dropdown menu doesn't work.

I'm relatively new to coding and learning by making this page. The dropdown menu should come from the 'collections' link with 2 other options.

The code for the carousel was edited from w3school.com and I have tried changing the margins so it doesn't overlap with my drop-down but no luck. Wondering if there is a problem with the jquery links I am using or if I have missed something from the code? I've taken some bits out below so there's not too much sorting through things that I didn't think were relevant (.main, .active, .drop-down container etc) but if I need to re-include them on here please let me know.

Any help would be very much appreciated! Many thanks.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
 href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/
 bootstrap.min.css">
<script 
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
 </script>
 <script 
 src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"> 
 </script>
 </head>

<body>

<style>   

#header {
text-align: left;
color: #294ccf;
position: absolute;
width: 300px;
height: 100px;
padding-left: 20px;}

h1  {
color: #294ccf;
font-family: arial;
font-weight: bold;
position:fixed;
font-size: 18pt;
text-decoration: none;
text-align: left}


.sidenav {
height: 100%;
width: 200px;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
    background-color: ;
overflow-x: hidden;
padding-top: 0px;
margin-top: 90px;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: 20px;
color: #294CCF;
font-style: normal;
font-variant: normal;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 12pt;
text-align: left;
text-decoration: none;}


.sidenav a, .dropdown-btn {
padding-top: 0px;
padding-right: 0px;
padding-left: 0px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
text-decoration: none;
font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 12pt;
color: #294CCF;
display: block;
border: none;
background: none;
width: 100%;
cursor: pointer;
outline: none;
position: relative;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: bold;
text-align: left;
line-height: normal;}


.fa-caret-down {
    float: right;
    padding-right: 8px;
    color: #294CCF; }

.carousel {margin-left 100px;
    margin-top:180px;}

.carousel-control.left, .carousel-control.right {
    background-image: none}


</style>


 <div id="header">
      <h1>Robyn Smith<br>Jewellery + objects</h1>
    </div>

<div class="sidenav">
<a href="bio.html">Bio</a>
<a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>

<button class="dropdown-btn">Collections
<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
</button>
<div class="dropdown-container">
<a href="sportsday.html">Sports Day</a>
<a href="artefacts.html">Putin</a>
</div></div>


<div class="container">

<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel" >
<!-- Wrapper for slides -->
<div class="carousel-inner">
  <div class="item active">
    <img src="img/sportsday1.jpg" alt="Badges" style="width:100%;">
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <img src="img/sportsday2.jpg" alt="Bag" style="width:100%;">
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <img src="img/sportsday3.jpg" alt="Neckpiece" style="width:100%;">
   </div>
 </div>

 <!-- Left and right controls -->
 <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
  <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" ></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
  <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" ></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Next</span>

  </a>

  </div>
 </div>

 <script>
 //* Loop through all dropdown buttons to toggle between hiding and showing its 
 dropdown content - This allows the user to have multiple dropdowns without any 
 conflict */
 var dropdown = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-btn");
 var i;

 for (i = 0; i < dropdown.length; i++) {
 dropdown[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
 this.classList.toggle("active");
 var dropdownContent = this.nextElementSibling;
 if (dropdownContent.style.display === "block") {
  dropdownContent.style.display = "none";
  } else {
  dropdownContent.style.display = "block";
  }
  });
  }

  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi Robyn. Welcome to Stackoverflow. Are you getting any errors in dev tools?

Answer (score 1):

The `script` in your body has a comment which is opened incorrectly. Comments in javascript can be:

- Single line: `// This is a single line comment`
- Multi line: `/* This is a multi line comment */`

Your code has the following line which breaks the application:

`//* Loop through all dropdown buttons to toggle between hiding and showing its 
 dropdown content - This allows the user to have multiple dropdowns without any 
 conflict */`

The compiler now only recognises this as a *single line comment* because of the `//` at the start, thus the rest of the code won't work anymore. The compiler now tries to interpret the lines such as *"dropdown content - ..."* as javascript, which is isn't. Remove the first slash to make it a multi line comment and your code should be fixed!

Answer (score 0):

There were multiple minor bugs. Scripts order were wrong. Bootrstrap requires jQuery, so it has to be put before. You also added some spaces to the Bootstrap CSS link, which broke it. It was:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" 
 href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/
 bootstrap.min.css">
<script 
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
 </script>
```

Fixed to:

```
<script
        src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

The comment was meant for one line, so it threw an error as well.
It was:

```
 //* Loop through all dropdown buttons to toggle between hiding and showing its 
 dropdown content - This allows the user to have multiple dropdowns without any 
 conflict */
```

Fixed to:

```
 /* Loop through all dropdown buttons to toggle between hiding and showing its 
 dropdown content - This allows the user to have multiple dropdowns without any 
 conflict */
```

Also removed some CSS lines that were not finished, just to keep you noticed.

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script
        src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">
</script>
</head>

<body>

<style>

    #header {
        text-align: left;
        color: #294ccf;
        position: absolute;
        width: 300px;
        height: 100px;
        padding-left: 20px;
    }

    h1 {
        color: #294ccf;
        font-family: arial;
        font-weight: bold;
        position: fixed;
        font-size: 18pt;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-align: left
    }


    .sidenav {
        height: 100%;
        width: 200px;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        padding-top: 0px;
        margin-top: 90px;
        margin-right: 0px;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
        margin-left: 20px;
        color: #294CCF;
        font-style: normal;
        font-variant: normal;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 12pt;
        text-align: left;
        text-decoration: none;
    }


    .sidenav a, .dropdown-btn {
        padding-top: 0px;
        padding-right: 0px;
        padding-left: 0px;
        padding-bottom: 0px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 12pt;
        color: #294CCF;
        display: block;
        border: none;
        background: none;
        width: 100%;
        cursor: pointer;
        outline: none;
        position: relative;
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: left;
        line-height: normal;
    }


    .fa-caret-down {
        float: right;
        padding-right: 8px;
        color: #294CCF;
    }

    .carousel {
        margin-left: 100px;
        margin-top: 180px;
    }

    .carousel-control.left, .carousel-control.right {
        background-image: none
    }


</style>


<div id="header">
    <h1>Robyn Smith<br>Jewellery + objects</h1>
</div>

<div class="sidenav">
    <a href="bio.html">Bio</a>
    <a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>

    <button class="dropdown-btn">Collections
        <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-container">
        <a href="sportsday.html">Sports Day</a>
        <a href="artefacts.html">Putin</a>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="container">

    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel">
        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <img src="img/sportsday1.jpg" alt="Badges" style="width:100%;">
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <img src="img/sportsday2.jpg" alt="Bag" style="width:100%;">
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <img src="img/sportsday3.jpg" alt="Neckpiece" style="width:100%;">
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Left and right controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>

        </a>

    </div>
</div>

<script>
    /* Loop through all dropdown buttons to toggle between hiding and showing its
    dropdown content - This allows the user to have multiple dropdowns without any
    conflict */
    var dropdown = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-btn");

    for (var i = 0; i < dropdown.length; i++) {
        dropdown[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
            this.classList.toggle("active");
            var dropdownContent = this.nextElementSibling;
            if (dropdownContent.style.display === "block") {
                dropdownContent.style.display = "none";
            } else {
                dropdownContent.style.display = "block";
            }
        });
    }

</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, very much appreciated! I made the changes and the page is working well now :)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly let's correct your css code basic syntax errors:

Head: Href for bootstrap.min.css can't be put into 2 lines. It must be kept on one line.

```
Body: line-height: normal, "sans-serif";
.sidenav: background-color: ; empty
.sidenav a:hover...: empty rulesets
.carousel: margin-left: 100px;
```

Your javascript is not commented correctly. Either use

- Single line comments // This is comments
- Multi line /* This is a comment */

Comment: Hi, thanks so much! I've tidied up the script and changed to multi line comments and its working hurrah!